# Ошибка записи числа в переменную Arduino

Tags: arduino

Ситуация в том что есть функция

```
void verticalRainbow(){
if(index == 0){
    color = 0;
    Serial.print((step = random()%230+10));
  }
  leds[index] = CHSV(color, 255, 255);
  leds[GRV(index++)] = CHSV(color, 255, 255);
  color+=step;
  index%=NUM_LEDS/2+1;
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(index);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(color);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(step);
}
```

Переменные index, color, step, NUM_LEDS, leds - глобальные
функция GRV возвращает обратное значение
Но это всё мелочи. Баг состоит в том что при выполнении строчки `Serial.print((step = random()%230+10));` пишется случайное число, а в step записывается 255. Почему это происходит и как это исправить? Я хочу е**ый рандом а не 255.
так же пытался использовать разнообразный рандом включая псевдо, а именно

```
step = random()%230+10
step = random(10, 240)
step = millis()%230+10
```

но результат всегда один и тот же. Как мне записать в step случайное число от 10 до 240?

Comment: Что такое `step`, какой тип, как объявлено?

Comment: `byte step = 0; ` так же когда пытался это поправить, пробовал использовать `int step = 0; ` результат был один и тот же

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать массив на 240 ячеек, пусть будет int.
Пусть будет переменная хранящая значение рандома, например х.
К слову:

```
     int x = step[random(10,240)];
```

Так же используйте

```
     randomSeed(analogRead(0));
```

Иначе последовательность чисел будет повторяться